# Dropdown Relacionando Outro em Loop

Tags: php, javascript

Esse script faz o seguinte: quando clicamos no primeiro dropdown ele abre um segundo dropdown.

Ok, até ai ele funciona perfeitamente. Mas o meu problema é que quando eu coloco ele dentro de um loop ele para de funcionar.

Então cada linha queria que repetisse esse script. Como não tenho conhecimento de javascript queria uma ajudinha para resolver isso

select.php

```
<script type="text/javascript"   
 src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $('#loader').hide();
 $('#show_heading').hide();
 $('#search_category_id').change(function(){
    $('#show_sub_categories').fadeOut();
    $('#loader').show();
    $.post("select2.php", {
        parent_id: $('#search_category_id').val(),
    }, function(response){
        setTimeout("finishAjax('show_sub_categories',   
 '"+escape(response)+"')", 400);
    });
    return false;

    });

    });
    function finishAjax(id, response){
    $('#loader').hide();
    $('#show_heading').show();
    $('#'+id).html(unescape(response));
    $('#'+id).fadeIn();
    } 
    function alert_id()
    {
    if($('#sub_category_id').val() == '')
    alert('Please select a sub category.');
    else
    alert($('#sub_category_id').val());
    return false;
    }
    </script>



<select name="id_dentista" style="text-transform: uppercase;"  class="form-control" id="search_category_id"  >

<option value="1">um</option>
<option value="2">dois</option>
<option value="28">Vinte e Oito</option>
```

```
    </div>

<label>Motorista:</label>
<div id="show_sub_categories" align="center" ></div>
```

select2.php

```
     <?php


if($_REQUEST){

$id_dentista     = $_REQUEST['id_dentista'];


echo "
<select name='id_motorista' id='sub_category_id'>"; 
 if($id_dentista == "28"){ // se marcele 

 echo"  
 <option value='or'>Ortodontia</option>
  <option value='cg2'>Clínico</option>
  <option value='pr'>Prótese</option>
  <option value='ed'>Endodontia</option>    
 ";
 }else{
 echo "
  '<option value='or'>Ortodontia</option>
  '<option value='cg'>Clínico</option>
 ";
 } 

 echo "</select>";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

O loop só vai funcionar se tiver index antes dos dados como segue um exemplo em array.

```
var dados = [

     0 => [
      'nome' => 'teste',
      'sobrenome' => 'teste1'
     ],
     1 => [
       'nome' => 'teste2',
       'sobrenome' => 'teste3'
     ] 
    ];
```

Dessa forma você consegue fazer um for no javascript usando jquery como mostra seu código é da seguinte forma.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    for(i = 0; dados.length; i++){
        console.log(dados[i]); // estou puxando dados do primeiro exemplo e passando os 2 indexs para um loop que faz a contagem no Length e soma até o fim da listagem.
    }
});
```

OBS: Os indexes que eu digo é o 0 e 1 se você fizer `console.log(dados.length);` você vai ver que ele retornará 2, ai dessa forma é possível de fazer um loop no javascript, se for em JSON mesma coisa, pega o JSON em variável e passa no LENGTH para contagem de indexes e faz a listagem no for.